# Accessing a specific website return always a 403 Forbidden error

Tags: indy

I try to read the website https://www.eroids.com/reviews with Indy and always get a 403.
This website seems only to load when I set the ssl version to sslvTLSv1_1. If I do that, this website loads fine, but other websites not. Most other seems to use sslvTLSv1_2.
As long I only add [sslvTLSv1_1] to the sslversion, it works, but when I add [sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2], the mentioned site does not load anymore (again 403), but any other site does.

My question is: How can I determine what sslversion a website need? Do I need to try to access the site with each ssl version until I get a 200 back or is there something to me unknown integrated into indy to automatically do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I determine what sslversion a website need?

In general, you can't.  However, most servers support *version negotiation* during the TLS handshake, so that clients supporting multiple/different TLS versions can negotiate with the server for which TLS version to use.  But, it sounds like maybe this particular server does not support that.

However, the fact that you are even getting an HTTP 403 response at all for an HTTPS url means a TLS session is being created fine, so the issue is something else.

Unless the server is ignoring all TLS errors during the handshake and creating a simple TLS session, THEN is sending an HTTP error in reply to an earlier TLS error. Which is rare, but not unheard of.

> Do I need to try to access the site with each ssl version until I get a 200 back

In this particular situation, probably so, yes.  Start with `[sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]`, and if that fails then retry with `[sslvTLSv1_2]`, then retry with `[sslvTLSv1_1]`, and so on.

> is there something to me unknown integrated into indy to automatically do that?

Indy does not have that capability at this time, no.